# Uncaught type Error: cannot read property 'x' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Can someone tell me where I went wrong? I have been looking at this for a hour and i can't see why it is not this.x is undefined.

it is somewhere here:

```
var canvas, canvasContext;

var blueCar = new carClass();

window.onload = function() {
    canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
    canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');

    colorRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height,'red');
    colorText("       LOADING...",canvas.width/3,canvas.height/2,'white',"30px Arial")

    loadImages();
}

function imageLoadingDoneSoStartGame(){
    var framesPerSecond = 30;
    setInterval(updateAll, 1000/framesPerSecond);
    setUpInput();
    bluecar.reset();
}

function updateAll() {
    moveAll();
    drawAll();
}

function moveAll() {
    blueCar.move();
    carTrackHandling();
}

function drawAll() {
    console.log(bluecar.x);
    drawTracks();
    blueCar.draw(blueCar);
}
```

here:

```
function carClass(){

    this.x = 75;
    this.y = 75;
    this.ang = 0;
    this.speed = 0;

    //reset car 1
    this.reset = function() {
        for(var eachRow=0;eachRow<TRACK_ROWS;eachRow++) {
            for(var eachCol=0;eachCol<TRACK_COLS;eachCol++) {

                var arrayIndex = rowColToArrayIndex(eachCol, eachRow); 

                if(trackGrid[arrayIndex] == TRACK_BLUE_START) {

                    trackGrid[arrayIndex] = TRACK_ROAD;
                    this.ang = -Math.PI/2;
                    this.x= eachCol * TRACK_W + TRACK_W/2;
                    this.y= eachRow * TRACK_H + TRACK_H/2;
                }//end of player start if
            }//end if col for
        }//end if row for
    }//end of car reser function

//move car 1
    this.move = function() {

        this.speed *= GROUND_SPEED_DECAY_MULT

        if(keyHeld_Gas){
            this.speed += DRIVE_POWER;
        }
        if(keyHeld_Reverse){
            this.speed -= REVERSE_POWER;
        }
        if(Math.abs(this.speed) > MIN_SPEED_TO_TURN){
            if(keyHeld_TurnLeft){
                this.ang -= TURN_RATE;
            }
            if(keyHeld_TurnRight){
                this.ang += TURN_RATE;
            }
        }
        this.x += Math.cos(this.ang) * this.speed;
        this.y += Math.sin(this.ang) * this.speed;

       // carAng += 0.02
    }

    this.draw = function(){
        drawBitmapCenteredWithRoatation(blueCarPic, this.x,this.y, this.ang);
    }
}
```

or here:

```
    function carTrackHandling(wichCar) {
    var carTrackCol = Math.floor(wichCar.x / TRACK_W);
    var carTrackRow = Math.floor(wichCar.y / TRACK_H);
    var trackIndexUnderCar = rowColToArrayIndex(carTrackCol, carTrackRow);

    if(carTrackCol >= 0 && carTrackCol < TRACK_COLS &&
        carTrackRow >= 0 && carTrackRow < TRACK_ROWS) {

        if(isObstacleAtColRow( carTrackCol,carTrackRow )) {

            //fixes bug
            wichCar.x -= Math.cos(wichCar.ang) * wichCar.speed;
            wichCar.y -= Math.sin(wichCar.ang) * wichCar.speed;

            //reduse speed and bounces car when hits a wall
            wichCar.speed*= -0.5;

        } // end of track found
    } // end of valid col and row
} // end of carTrackHandling func
```

the exact error i am getting is:

where Track.js: is : var carTrackCol = Math.floor(wichCar.x / TRACK_W);

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
at carTrackHandling (Track.js:34)
at moveAll (Main.js:29)
at updateAll (Main.js:23)
```

any help is appreciated in finding it, and telling me what I did wrong thankyou.

Comment: `at carTrackHandling (Track.js:34)` tells you that error is exactly at line 34 of your file Track.js. It is just 1 line, don't take hours to read it! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your function is defined as `function carTrackHandling(wichCar) {`. It takes one parameter, which is the car that (I assume) you want to handle.

If your `moveAll()` function, you're not passing in a car to your function. When your function tries to access `x` of `whichCar` it throws an error because it's undefined (As it was not passed any car). Pass the car you want to handle as shown below in your `moveAll()` function:

```
carTrackHandling();
```

It should be:

```
blueCar.move();
carTrackHandling(blueCar);
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you are passing anything to `carTrackHandeling()` and it is expecting to be passed an object.

It looks like you are calling it here with no parameters.

```
function moveAll() {
   blueCar.move();
   carTrackHandling();
}
```

Then when you make it to this function `whichCar` would be undefined causing the error you are seeing.

```
function carTrackHandling(wichCar) {
   var carTrackCol = Math.floor(wichCar.x / TRACK_W);
    ...
}
```